# Heroku Database save issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying store the number of views for every *workshop*.

My Workshops controller is:

```
  def show    
    @workshop.view = @workshop.view + 1
    @workshop.save
  end
```

The view column in the schema:

```
  create_table "workshops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "view",         default: 0
  end
```

So I expect every time show action works, this will increase the view number by 1. It's working in local, bur on heroku view column is every time 0. I could not find the reason.

Maybe it's because of PG database. Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Do you have any validations in your Workshop.rb file? Are you caching in production?  Try it locally but start the server with:  rails server -e production    and see if it works then.  That will load your production config.

Comment: use `@workshop.save!` instead of  `@workshop.save` and check `heroku logs -t`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is gone after I did : heroku restart.
It's probably because I did not restart the heroku server after rake db:migrate.